# how to make an iframe with some height and 100% width across all devices i.e desktop and mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

hello friends i have a blog that will give students' results by an iframe. it is displayed fine in desktop but in the mobile browser the iframe is getting narrowed in width 100% as I have given.To be more specific, [look at my web page](http://www.diplomaticengineers.com/p/jntuhresults_52.html?id=4&name=RCRV_MBA_AUG16M&type=d)
and [look at another page](http://engineershub.in//jntu-hyderabad-b-tech-b-pharmacy-1st-year-2-2-and-3-2-r13-r09-r07-supplementary-exam-results-october-2016)(and after getting into this page please click on any of the links named link-1 or link-2)this is nice i want my above page to be like this.the iframe in this page also gets narrowed but in some other way.The main problem here is the second page responses cleanly but mine is not that much clear what should I do to be like that. thanks in advance.

Note:you will not notice my problem unless you click on link-1 or link-2 in the second page given above because the iframe is opened after clicking on those links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the iframes div tag with the same class that they have. Their div tag has a class called eh-box. Their div tag is more like a pop up as well.

The eh box class contains this css

```
.eh-box {

top: 10%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
float: none;
width: 98%;
height: 600px !important;
background: #ffffff;

margin: 0 auto;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;

}
```

Comment: If anything use the inspector tool from the browser. Youll find it very useful